# BioPython AlignIO sequences must be the same length [multiple files]

Tags: python, alignment, biopython

I got an issue when I try to align multiple files

Here is my script:

```
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment

from Bio.Align.Applications import ClustalOmegaCommandline


def divergence(fic1dna,fic2dna,fic1prot,fic2prot):

    from Bio import SeqIO


    seq1dna = list(SeqIO.parse(fic1dna, "fasta",alphabet=IUPAC.IUPACUnambiguousDNA()))
    seq2dna = list(SeqIO.parse(fic2dna, "fasta",alphabet=IUPAC.IUPACUnambiguousDNA()))
    seq1prot = list(SeqIO.parse(fic1prot, "fasta",alphabet=IUPAC.protein))
    seq2prot= list(SeqIO.parse(fic2prot, "fasta",alphabet=IUPAC.protein))

    u=0

    while u < len(seq1dna): # make an alignment betwen each element on 2 files for 2 paires files 


        nuc1=str(seq1dna[u].seq)
        nuc2=str(seq2dna[u].seq)
        prot1=str(seq1prot[u].seq)
        prot2=str(seq2prot[u].seq)


        prot1 = SeqRecord(Seq(prot1, alphabet=IUPAC.protein),id='pro1') 
        prot2 = SeqRecord(Seq(prot2, alphabet=IUPAC.protein),id='pro2')

        aln = MultipleSeqAlignment([prot1, prot2]) 

        print(aln)

        u+=1


print(divergence("concatenate_0035_fna_renamed.fst","concatenate_0042_fna_renamed.fst","concatenate_0035_faa_renamed.fst","concatenate_0042_faa_renamed.fst"))
```

So, as you can see I have 4 files, corresponding to 244 sequences from 2 species and I need to calculate dN dS for each of them so, I need to align each paired seq in codon alignment.

But, when I'm trying to align my 244 protein sequences, the error " ValueError("Sequences must all be the same length") raises "

I do not know why the script does not accept sequence with different length since all other programmes do.

short input would be :

one file with the AA seq from the sp 1

```
>EOG090X005Q
CEHNTAGRDCEKCLDFYNDAPWGRASPTNVHECKACNCNGFSNKCYFDKDLYERTGHGGHCIDCEENRDGANCERCKENFYQGMEDICLPCNCNPTGSRSLQCNAEGKCQCKPGVTGDKCDVCAPNYFEFTMHGCKPCDCNVSGSYGNTPQCDPQTGVCLCKQNVEGRRCRECKPGFFNLDVENEFGCTPCFCFGHSSQCSSAPKYQAHEISAHYIRDAEKWGAEDDQRKPVQLQFNANTQNIAVASKGSEILYFLASGQFLGDQRPSYNHDLKFTLRLGESGGYPSSQDIILEGARSSVSMNIYAQNNPEPSDVAQEYSFRLHEDPRYGWTPTLSNFEFMSILQNLTAIKIRGTYNKGGVGYLINFKLETAKIGREKGSAPANWVEKCSCPKAYVGDYCEECAPGYKHEPANGGPYSTCIPCDCNGHAHICDTATGFCICKHNTTGSNCELCAKGFYGNAIAGTADDCKPCPCPKDSGCIQLMDQSIVCTDCPVGYAGPRCEVCADAHFGDPTGQFGAPQECEECQCNGNVDPNAVGNCNRTTGECLKCIYNTAGEHCDKCLSGYFGDALDQKKKGDCKPCQCLEAGTVESPEGARKAPLCDGLTGFCSCRPHVIGRNCDKCEVDLNCIAVLKT
>EOG090X00BV
MNAHFPQNEIARSEAYNIMSVRKQYLVPKDGTPLSGLIQDHVISGVKMSIRGAFFTKADYQQLVFQALSNHKGEIKLLPPTILKPIMLWSGKQILSTIIINSIPKGKPYLSLTGKAKISSKAWQKEPARTWNAGGTPFTNPNSMSEAEVIIRKGELLCGVLDKTHYGATPYGLVHCMYELYGGDSSSALLSSFSKVFTFYLQWIGFTLGVKDILVVEEADKQRDNFINLVRKVGKVAAAKATELPVDVDELKLKETISEMLIKDPKFRANLDRQYKSLLDSYTNNINTVCLSEGLLEKFPYNNLQLMVQSGAKGSTVNTMQISCLLGQIELEGKRPPLMISGRSLPSFPPYDISPRAGGFIDGRFMTGIQPQEFFFHCMAGREGLIDTAVKTSRSGYLQRCLIKHLEGLSVAYDHTVRDSDSSVIQFAYGEDGLDVIKCQYFNKDQFEFLDVNSNAVISKSAIKKLKEDDKSKALAKSQKSLKKWKKKNGNPFEKVRYSPFTEFSAIAKNDIVLDDKPTDQTRDPNYWELEKMWRNLDADEKKQYARKRCPDPIPSKYSPEYKFGVINEQLNELTQNYLKNRKEHMYSDYTDKDKFTEIINAKYLASMAAPGEPVGLLAAQSIGEPSTQMTLNTFHFAGRGDMNVTLGIPRLREILMTASAKLKTPSMDIPFRSDLPDLNKKAERLRQKMNRVTVSDVLEKIDVHCEIVTNPNRQLKTVMRFSFLPHSQYKVQYTVKPAQIIKHMQNKFFSEMFSIIRKQAKTTCGVMWSTEKEKKRRAASDEDDEDGEGASPDVAEKAVNMDEDSSDEEGPNDDDDNTDVS
```

and the other for the specie 2:

```
>EOG090X005Q
MGGKIAAILLFAFFTSGSRSEPDFVDGQFNKINKNRVEVKCYDDFGAPQRCIPPFENAAFGVLMEATNTCGQDGRPTEFCRQTGVQRKPCEFCHPGDHPASFLTDRDNNDNATWWQSETMHEGIEYPNKVVLTLNLGKTYDITYVRVLFESPRPESWGIFRRRTEDSPWEPYQFYSATCRDTYGLPDRKDTVRGEDTRVLCTSEYSDISPLRRGTVAFSTLEGRPSAFQFDTNPALQSWVQATDLRLSLDRPNTFGDELFGDGQVLKSYYYAIADVAVGARCACNGHAGECINSPHTNGTTRRVCRCEHNTAGPDCNECLPFYNDAPWGRATTTDAHECKPCNCNGYSDRCYFDKDLYERSGHGGHCTDCRANRAGPNCERCRENFYQRLEDSYCVACNCNEIGSRSLQCNSEGKCQCKPGITGDKCDRCAANFFNFDSLGCTSCECSPKGSLDNEPNCDPVSGACVCKENVEGKRCRECRPGFFNLDLDNEFGCTPCFCYGHSSVCNLANGYSKLTIESMFGRGNEKWTASVAGNPIPLHYDAVTQTISVNAPDRDNVYFVAPERFLGDQRASYNQDLTFTLRIAENEPAPTARDVILEGGNGEQLTQPIFGQTNQLPNASPQVYKFRLNEHADYGWEPRVTSRAFMSVLSNLTAIKIRGTYTHQGRGFLDDVSLETAQRGAAGEPADWIEHCQCPHGYVGQFCESCAPGFHHDPPNGGPFSLCVPCNCNGHADICEAETGQCICHHNTAGSNCDLCSRGFYGYPLKGTPHDCKPCPCPDNGPCILLGNNPDPICSECPSGRTGARCETCSDGYFGNPDQGQACRLCDCNNNIDLNAVRNCNHETGECLKCVNNTAGFHCEDCLSGYWGDALSERKEDSCKLCQCYPPGTIELDDGSVAPCNQLTGHCACKPHVIGRNCDKCEDGYYQILSGDGCTACNCDPEGSYNRTCDATTGQCECRPGITGKRCDTCLPYQFGFGRDGCKHCDCDTIGSQELQCDASGQCPCLTNVEGRRCDRCKENKYNRQYGCIDCPPCYNLIQDSVNQHRRRLNELESTLRKINNSPTVMKDSDFEKELKNVENRVKSLLQVAKQGSGNENKTLVEQLDELRDQLNQIEKISQSVDATAEDARRTTNEGLTSIEEAERVLDQIYEQLTEAEDYLATDGARALAAAKKRADQVGQQNQQMTIIAQEARVLADLNTNEAKKIHVLAEQARNTSLEAYNLAKKAIAKYSNISDEIRGLENKLELLEDRFNEVKNLTAAAVAKSAAVDKEALQLLILDLRVPAVDTNELRILLETVSVDGSEIKEQAQLLLGQNEAWLNELANKARKSEELLERAQDQQAATADLLSEVDGANEKAKDALKRGNQTLVEAQETLKKLGEFDAEVQKERIKAQEALTVLEEIKDMVNEAIAKANETESVLKDAESNAIAAKDIAIQAQVSNNADEASANANLIRQEANKTKLDAVRLGNEADKLHLRVEITNSIAKKHEARVDKDVNATNEVNHQVGQARNSLNLAGQQVDKALAEVDEIIKELDVLPEIDDADLDRLEERLLAAEKEIEEANLEKRIRELTEAKNLQTQWVKNYEDEVSRLRLEVENIDDIRKALPSICYKRLRLEP
>EOG090X00BV
MFSIFTASDVRNLSVLKISTPLSFNILGHPLKGGLYDPALGPLNDRSDPCGTCGEGTIQCMGHFGHIELPVPVVNPLFHKVLTSLLKLSCLKCYTLQIPSYLKLLLNGKLRLMEEGFSNDIPGLEQEVGSAVAGMNRIAEGELEFISDIIEAYIEMTCNQRHHVQSGKSKESTSTRTLNMEWHHYIESVVKTCKASKLCINCRNPIPKMTILKNKILTNHVVNNEDTMMEDRVIHKLETSFMTPDQSKKHLRGLWQKEADILRIIIPCLGSVDLEFPTDVFFFEIIPVLPPITRPVNMLDNQLVEHPQSQVYKSIIQDCLVLRNIIQTIQDGDTTQLPEEGRAVFDEIRGDNAAEKLHHAWTTLQSNVDHLMDREMSKTTESANCHGLKQVIEKKEGIIRMHMMGKRVNYAARSVITPDPNLNIDEIGVPEAFALKLTYPVPVTPWNVTELRKLIINGPEIHPGAVMIEGEDGFVKLLRGDDKTQLEAIAKRLLTSSRKPFSGIKIVHRHLQNGDMLLLNRQPTLHKPSIMAHKARILKGEKTLRLHYANCKAYNADFDGDEMNAHFPQNELARSEGYFIANVSNQYLVPKDGTPLGGLIQDHVISGVRLTLRGNFFNRQDYMQLVYSAIADTTGDLILLPPTILKPVRLWSGKQIISTVIINLTPRGRAPINLKASAKISVKDWQVKKARKWKCGQEFTDQRTMSEAEVVIRGGELLSGVLDKTHYGATPYGLIHCLFELYGGTCSSKVLSAFGKLFQTYLQISGFTLGVEDILVVRKSDQKRREIIEACRQIGDQIQTATVELPPGTSEEQVKSKMEESYAKDPKFRAIVDRKYKSALDVFTNNINKTCLPAGLLKKFPHNNLQLMVQSGAKGSTVNTMQISCLLGQIELEGKRPPLMINGKSLPSFPAYDSSPRSGGFIDGRFMTGIQPQEFFFHCMAGREGLIDTAVKTSRSGYLQRCLIKHLEGLTVNYDSTVRDSDGSLIQMSYGEDGLDIPNSRFLRKEELDFLVENRKAIVDPALVEHLKDETTEKIRKINKKIRKWRTKHGNGSTKWRNSEFAKFSEINRNSGSSKNRQINSNCGRTKAALSLMKKWIRADEEVKKKLKDECVRCPDPVTSIFRQDLQFGVLTEKMEALMEEYLDEKSRRFTTSIGKEEVRDLLCTKIMKSLCPPGEPVGLLAAQSIGEPSTQMTLNTFHFAGRGEMNVTLGIPRLREILMMASKNIKTPSMEIPFRTDLPNVENQATKLQLKLTKCYLSNILKNIKLDRKLEENPNRQLTFTLTVNCLPHKFYKNEYCVKPHNVLNEIERNFFKLFFRAIKKIGKATGTLLHIEEEKSSSREDDAMLDTGEPDETEAKPNRSDLGELHESSDEDEAAEDADATASRSIARHRENQEYEDPEEEEIEDAAPREPEDEENPQNPTNLPPEDEDDLDQPMCVADELITEQRKKDVVNMHPYALDYDYDSEKFLWCKLTFWLPLRMCRLDLPTILRTVAEKVVLWETPAIKRAFTFQNSEGETILKTDGLNIVEMFKYAQILDLHKLYTNDIYGVSRTYGIEAANRVILKEVKDVFKMYGITVDSRHLSLIADYMTFDGTFQPLSRKGMEDSASPLQQMSFEASLNFLKNATLQGKHDDLMSPSSRLMVGQPCKTGTGAFNVLFKMNNTAVSM
```

Someone could help me?
Thanks you

Comment: `MultipleSeqAlignment` does *not* perform an alignment, it is a class for representing sequences that are *already* aligned https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/Align/__init__.py#L19 You are trying to call `MultipleSeqAlignment` on un-aliged sequences, instead perform the alignment first with `ClustalOmegaCommandline` or something else

Comment: can you provide short input and desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your help; I found ClustalOmegaCommandline before but it needs an input file with the 2 sequences un-aligned and I do not want to creat 244 files for each  sequence, instead to add : ClustalOmegaCommandline(infile=in_file_prot, outfile= out_file_prot,verbose=True, auto=True,seqtype="protein",force=True), I would like to add: alnprot = ClustalOmegaCommandline(prot1 , prot2,verbose=True, auto=True,seqtype="protein",force=True). I add the desired input, and for the out put i would be juste the sequences aligned for exmple: seq1 vs seq1 : alignment ; etc

Comment: I need to do those alignments because i want to make a codon alignment for each seq such that :  codon_aln = codonalign.build(alnprot, [nuc1, nuc2])

Comment: I finally used alns = pairwise2.align.globalds(prot1 , prot2, matrix, gap_open, gap_extend) and now it work thanks you